# create-react-app exclude/include/change code parts at build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, preprocessor, create-react-app

I'm developing a React web app and I'm using the `create-react-app` npm utility.
My app communicates with a server which, during development, is on my local machine. For this reason all the Ajax request I make use a `localhost:port` address.

Of course, when I'm going to build and deploy my project in production I need those addresses to change to the production ones.
I am used to the `preprocess` Grunt plugin flow (https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess) which has the possibility to mark parts of code to be excluded, included or changed at build time.

For example:

```
//@if DEV
const SERVER_PATH = "localhost:8888";
//@endif
//@if !DEV
const SERVER_PATH = "prot://example.com:8888";
//@endif
```

Do you know if there is a way to do such thing inside the `create-react-app` development environment?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure exactly how your server-side code handles requests, however you shouldn't have to change your code when deploying to production if you use relative paths in your ajax queries. For example, here's an ajax query that uses a relative path:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "something/getthing/",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function ( data ) {
        //do a thing
    }
});
```

Hopefully that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

When creating your networkInterface, use the `process.env.NODE_ENV` to determine what `PATH` to use.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const SERVER_PATH = "localhost:8888";
}
else {
    const SERVER_PATH = "prot://example.com:8888";
}
```

Your application will automatically detect whether you are in production or development and therefore create the const SERVER_PATH with the correct value for the environment.

Comment: Will it work also if I'm in the browser? I guess not. But I guess I can check for the window.location. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "in the browser"? If you build your application and run it in a browser directly?

Comment: If you run your app using Node.js directly, the application will detect that you are in a `development ` environment. If you build your application and use the **built** version, the application will detect that you are in a `production` environment.

Comment: I mean that I'm not making a React Native app but a Web App with React DOM. Are you saying that my HTML page will be able to access `process.env` because I've launched it through `npm start`?

Comment: I usually start my **application** through a **js** file, but I think the same logic applies to your situation. Following this logic, `npm start` would use the **development` environment and `npm run build` would use the **production** environment.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development), the dev server can proxy your requests. You can configure it in your `package.json` like this:

```js
 "proxy": "http://localhost:4000",
```

Another option is to ask the browser for the current location. It works well when your API and static files are on the same backend, which is common with Node.js and React.

Here you go:

```js
const { protocol, host } = window.location
const endpoint = protocol + host

// fetch(endpoint)
```